# Add voice messages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, answers, privileges

Can we get the possibility to add voice messages to questions and answers?

Maybe you could also make it a privilege.

This would be very useful (for example, on language Stack Exchange sites to show and improve the pronunciation).

Comment: But on Stack Overflow... Is there any use at all for pronunciation?

Comment: @DavyM: Of course! We still have to clarify, how to pronounce e.g. GIF. Do you pronounce it like "gift" or like "ginger"? ;)

Comment: MSE duplicate: [Ask/answer question through voice recording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200033)

Comment: It's already a feature. It's in the accessibility settings of your computer.

Answer (score 15):

This is on the wrong site (this should have been posted on https://meta.stackexchange.com if you want to suggest features for Stack Exchange sites in general) and on those sites where sound makes sense, **it is already supported**. See [Can an embedded audio player be added to Audio.SE and Music.SE?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/72365)

There is no point in such a feature on Stack Overflow. We deal in code here, not in language or music or other subjects where audio is relevant. I see zero reason to enable the embedded audio player support here.

Answer (score 8):

While this might be a useful feature on some of the spoken language sites, I don't see it being very useful on Stack Overflow, where questions about how to pronounce words would be off-topic. Any other use of the feature would be counter-productive, as voice messages are not easily indexed and searched, and plain text is.